# Dynamically create HTML textbox from spring controller

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot

I'm creating textboxs according to numbers of selected items in a drop down (for example , if 2 items are selected in a drop down 2 textboxs are created dynamically).

On save I'm managing to get data entered from those dynamicalli created textboxs.

On update , as the page is refreshed I'm not able to recreate those textboxs and hence unable to edit those dynamically created textboxs.

Need to create textbox dynamically from the controller and add it to a perticular div in HTML page.

How can I achive this?

Answer (score 0):

You can return a string from the controller and specify `Content-Type: text/html`

```
@GetMapping(value = "/html", produces = MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE)
public String getHtml() {
    return "your html code";
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate